# kotlinのREPL呼び出し時エラーについて

Tags: java, kotlin

今日、kotlinのコンパイラをインストールをし、環境変数も通した後、
$kotlincでREPLを呼び出そうとすると以下のエラーとなります。

```
c:\>kotlinc
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.2.71 (JRE 1.8.0_144-_2017_08_24_19_19-b00)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit
exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.history.DefaultHistory.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.history.DefaultHistory.save(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.reader.ConsoleReplCommandReader.flushHistory(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.ReplFromTerminal.doRun(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.ReplFromTerminal.access$doRun(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.ReplFromTerminal$Companion.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(Unknown Source)
```

Javaが何か関係あるのでしょうか。

どうかお助け頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: FYI: https://teratail.com/questions/152944#reply-229828

Comment: 解決した場合は、自己回答ができますので回答をお願いします。

Comment: 勘違いさせてしまったようで申し訳ないのですが、自己回答も普通の回答と同じように「何が原因でどのようにしたら問題が解決されたのか」を文章にしてください。今回であれば「KotlinコンパイラをA.zipでインストールしてしまったのが原因で、B.zipでインストールしなおすことで解決しました」のような文章になるかと思います。